# Join by target in Criteria API

Tags: java, sql, database, persistence, criteria-api

I have a problem with Join in Criteria API - I need to execute this SQL:
    
    `SELECT eventConf.DEPT_ID FROM EVENT_CONF eventConf
    JOIN EVENT event ON event.EVENT_CONF_ID = eventConf.ID
    JOIN TASK task ON task.EVENT_ID = event.ID;`

Problem is, that when try to "translate" this into Criteria API classes,
like this:

```
Subquery<Long> subquery3 = cq.subquery(Long.class);
Root<EventConf> subquery3Root = subquery3.from(EventConf.class);
Join<EventConf, Event> eventJoin = subquery3Root.join(Event_.eventConf);
```

My IDE shows me, that

```
Cannot resolve method 'join(javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute<atc.edpo.source.entity.Event,atc.edpo.source.entity.EventConf>)
```

It is understandable, because Event_.evenConf is type of **SingularAttribute< Event, EventConf >** and **Root** parameterized as **EventConf**, but how do you make a Join, when target entity contains id of source entity? Or can I make some kind of analog of Join in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

```
*You can use FetchMode
Criteria critiera = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(EventConf.class);
critiera.setFetchMode("event", FetchMode.JOIN)
          .setFetchMode("task", FetchMode.JOIN)
           .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
critiera.list();*
```

Comment: Sorry, but  this won't help, because i need to use CriteriaQuery(like main query, thats why I am using Subquery in the example, because all I need, it's just make Predicate for the main query, like DEPT_ID from what I selected is equal to user's DEPT_ID) and CriteriaBuilder. So the main question - is the there any way to make join when target entity contains reference to source with these classes.